# Knockout bootstrap ul set active li

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I want to set a list item's CSS to active when clicked. I have a working implementation, but I also need to remove the active class from any other `li` elements within the `ul` element.

```
<div class="row">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: cats" class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="click: catSelected, css: { active: isCatChosen() == true}">
     <span data-bind="text: catName"></span>
     <span class="badge" data-bind="text: catClicks"></span>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    var CatsViewModel = function() {
            var catList = this;

            catList.cat = ko.observable();

            catList.cats = ko.observableArray([
                    {   'catName' : 'Twins',
                        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
                        'catImage' : 'img/funnyCat.jpg',
                        'isCatChosen': ko.observable(false),
                        'catSelected': function() {
                                            this.isCatChosen(true);
                                        } 
                    }, {
                        'catName' : 'Leopard',
                        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
                        'catImage' : 'img/leopard.jpg',
                        'isCatChosen': ko.observable(false),
                        'catSelected': function() {
                                            this.isCatChosen(true);
                                        } 
                    },{
                        'catName' : 'Blue Eyes',
                        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
                        'catImage' : 'img/blueEyes.jpg',
                        'isCatChosen': ko.observable(false),
                         'catSelected': function() {
                                            this.isCatChosen(true);
                                        } 
                     },{
                        'catName' : 'Mountain Lion',
                        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
                        'catImage' : 'img/mountainLion.jpg',
                        'isCatChosen': ko.observable(false),
                         'catSelected': function() {
                                            this.isCatChosen(true);
                                        } 
                     },{
                        'catName' : 'Painted Lion',
                        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
                        'catImage' : 'img/paintedlion.jpg',
                        'isCatChosen': ko.observable(false),
                         'catSelected': function() {
                                            this.isCatChosen(true);
                                        } 
                    }
             ]);
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new CatsViewModel());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're making the `active` item exclusive, you should keep track of that in the `CatsViewModel`.  Each of the individual cats doesn't need to know if it's active or not.

```
<div class="row">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: cats" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="click: $parent.catSelected,
                                               css: { active: $parent.isCatChosen($data) }">
            <span data-bind="text: catName"></span>
            <span class="badge" data-bind="text: catClicks"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
var CatsViewModel = function(cats) {
    var catList = this;
    catList.activeCat = ko.observable();
    catList.cats = ko.observableArray(cats);

    catList.isCatChosen = function (cat) {
        return catList.activeCat() === cat;
    };
    catList.catSelected = function (cat) {
        catList.activeCat(cat);
    };
};
```

You could then remove all the unnecessary methods and other properties that you added to each of the cats.

```
var cats = [
    {
        'catName' : 'Twins',
        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
        'catImage' : 'img/funnyCat.jpg',
    }, {
        'catName' : 'Leopard',
        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
        'catImage' : 'img/leopard.jpg',
    },{
        'catName' : 'Blue Eyes',
        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
        'catImage' : 'img/blueEyes.jpg',
    },{
        'catName' : 'Mountain Lion',
        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
        'catImage' : 'img/mountainLion.jpg',
    },{
        'catName' : 'Painted Lion',
        'catClicks' : ko.observable(0),
        'catImage' : 'img/paintedlion.jpg',
    }
];
ko.applyBindings(new CatsViewModel(cats));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kz5978n/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.list-group li').click(function(){
    $('list-group li').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');     
    });
    $(this).addClass('active');     
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h3erdxbL/